# optimization of case statement in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

add two more set of case conditions to see if this will helping getting optimized..

I need to optimize case statement as it is too length..i have 1500 lines with similar case statement in the query. i have just pick one set of that query for optimization

```
select 
          case when ((
                    lower (id) like '%hol%' 
                  or lower (campaign_name) like '%hol%' 
                  or lower (marketing_source_code) like '%hol%' 
                  or lower (call_to_action) like '%hol%'
                  or lower(program_type) like '%hol%'
                  or lower (campaign_lvl1_name) like '%hol%'
                  or lower (campaign_lvl2_name) like '%hol%'
                  or lower (campaign_lvl3_name) like '%hol%'
                  or lower (campaign_lvl4_name) like '%hol%'
                )            
         and not (position ('HOLLYWOOD' in upper(campaign_name)) > 0 or 
                  position ('HOLE' in upper(campaign_name)) > 0 or
                  position ('HOLDER' in upper(campaign_name)) > 0 or
                  position ('STOCKHOLM' in upper(campaign_name)) > 0 or
                  position ('HOLIDAY' in upper(campaign_name)) > 0 or
                  position ('CATHOLIC' in upper(campaign_name)) > 0 or
                  position ('HOLISTIC' in upper(campaign_name)) > 0 or
                  position ('HOLY' in upper(campaign_name)) > 0 or
                  position ('HOLTKAMP' in upper(campaign_name)) > 0 or
                  position ('HOLDING' in upper(campaign_name)) > 0 or
                  position ('CUSTHOLRECP' in upper(campaign_name)) > 0 
                 )
         and (  position('VSOM' in upper(campaign_name) ) > 0 
                 or position('VSPHERE WITH OPERATIONS MANAGEMENT' in upper(campaign_name)) > 0
                 or position('VSOM' in upper(products) ) > 0  
                 or position('VSPHERE WITH OPERATIONS MANAGEMENT' in upper(products)) > 0
             )) 
         then 1 else 0 end as vsom_hol_response,
case when (( 
                    lower (campaign_name) like '%seminar%' 
                 or lower (marketing_source_code) like '%seminar%'  
                 or lower (call_to_action) like '%seminar%'
                 or lower (program_type) like '%seminar%'
                 or lower (campaign_lvl1_name) like '%seminar%'
                 or lower (campaign_lvl2_name) like '%seminar%'
                 or lower (campaign_lvl3_name) like '%seminar%'
                 or lower (campaign_lvl4_name) like '%seminar%'
               )                       
         and (      position('VSOM' in upper(campaign_name) ) > 0 
                or  position('VSPHERE WITH OPERATIONS MANAGEMENT' in upper(campaign_name)) > 0
                or position('VSOM' in upper(products) ) > 0  
                or position('VSPHERE WITH OPERATIONS MANAGEMENT' in upper(products)) > 0
             ))
            then 1 else 0 end as vsom_seminar_response,    
   case when ((
                    lower (id) like '%webinar%' 
                 or lower (campaign_name) like '%webinar%' 
                 or lower (marketing_source_code) like '%webinar%' 
                 or lower (call_to_action) like '%webinar%'
                 or lower (program_type) like '%webinar%'
                 or lower (campaign_lvl1_name) like '%webinar%'
                 or lower (campaign_lvl2_name) like '%webinar%'
                 or lower (campaign_lvl3_name) like '%webinar%'
                 or lower (campaign_lvl4_name) like '%webinar%'
                 )                       
            and (      
                   position('VSOM' in upper(campaign_name) ) > 0 
                or position('VSPHERE WITH OPERATIONS MANAGEMENT' in upper(campaign_name)) > 0
                or position('VSOM' in upper(products) ) > 0  
                or position('VSPHERE WITH OPERATIONS MANAGEMENT' in upper(products)) > 0)
                 )
         then 1 else 0 end as vsom_webinar_response

             from base.vdim_campaign
```

Comment: Note: `CASE` is not a *statement*. It is a *conditional expression*.

Comment: thanks,, k.. so how do i optimize this case conditions

Comment: why check for the position of something why not just  'VSOM' in (upper(campaign_name))  it adds work when it doesn't need to.  2nd.  the upper/lowers add cost.  You could have function based indexes on all columns doing lower/upper to avoid having to do it in the SQL.  The cost is at the time it's stored/updated and not on data retrieval then.    next, any request to improve performance should include the execution plan so we can focus on acutal bottlenecks; not perceived ones.  lastly dual percents on a like are unable to use indexes.  avoid where you can.

Comment: Wait... is this question about performance optimization or code length optimization?  you say optimization, but then mention `case statement as it is too length`

Comment: Why is campaign_name `not in` and `in` used in the same case statement?  Just use the in and be done with it...   The logic here is too confusing to even attempt to shorten in my opinion.